# How to remove HTML escape sequence characters from the string in PHP?

Tags: php, html, string, html-entities, html-escape-characters

Suppose, I've a following string variable containing such kind of string.

```
$sample_String = "Dummy User graded your comment \"\r\n\t\t\t\t\tdoc_ck.docx\r\n\t\t\t\t\tDownload\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\" that you posted.";
```

Now I don't want these HTML characters in my string.

How should I remove them in an efficient and reliable way? I want the final output string as follows :

```
$sample_String = "Dummy User graded your comment \"doc_ck.docx Download\" that you posted.";
```

When it will be shown in a browser the `'\'` appearing before " will get disappear and the string in a browser will look like below :

**Dummy User graded your comment "doc_ck.docx Download" that you posted.**

Isn't it?

Thanks.

Till now I've tried below code but no success :

```
function br2nl($buff = '') {
    $buff = mb_convert_encoding($buff, 'HTML-ENTITIES', "UTF-8");
    $buff = preg_replace('#<br[/\s]*>#si', "\n", $buff);
    $buff = trim($buff);

    return $buff;
  }
$sample_String = br2nl(stripslashes(strip_tags($sample_String)));
```

Comment: Those aren't HTML entities, but C escapes. With [`stripcslashes`](http://php.net/stripcslashes) one could recover the original characters. Or strip them per regex (before or afterwards).

Comment: @mario : Please check my updated question with the code I tried.

Comment: Sorry. This makes it even more unclear as to what's going on. Where does the input string originate from now? How does it really look? (`var_dump` as block text). Or is the `$sample_String = "…";` assignment how it literally looks in your code? (Because then the escapes would already be expanded). -- More context please. (Imagine you had to guess what the purpose is..)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to remove `\r` (carrige return) `\n` (newline) and `\t` (tab) you can do:

```
$string = "Dummy User graded your comment \"\r\n\t\t\t\t\tdoc_ck.docx\r\n\t\t\t\t\tDownload\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\" that you posted.";
$string = str_replace(array("\r", "\n", "\t"), "", $string);
```

If you want to preserve the newlines (and have them show up in the browser) do:

```
$string = "Dummy User graded your comment \"\r\n\t\t\t\t\tdoc_ck.docx\r\n\t\t\t\t\tDownload\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\" that you posted.";
$string = nl2br(str_replace(array("\r", "\t"), "", $string));
```

---

HTMLentities are sequences like `&quot;` and `&#063;`

Comment: Please check my updated question with the code I tried.

Answer (score 1):

Use a regex like so:

```
<?php
$str = "Dummy User graded your comment \"\r\n\t\t\t\t\tdoc_ck.docx\r\n\t\t\t\t\tDownload\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\" that you posted.";
echo preg_replace('/[\r\n\t]+/m','',$str);
```